Apache config return IPV6 instead of IPV4
htaccess file looks like this because I only want to give access to authorized ip ranges:
#ErrorDocument 403 "Sorry ! You are not authorized to access this page"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php

#CLIENT 1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.x\.137\.[0-255]

#CLIENT 2
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^y\.y\.y\.65

#CLIENT 3
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.x\.[0-255]\.[0-255]

#CLIENT 4
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.x\.x\.[0-255]

#CLIENT 5
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x.x.x.x

RewriteRule ^.*$  error.html [L]
</IfModule>

For example, One of my client 3's collaborators tried to access my site via the dedicated url (VirtualHost) but he landed on my 403 error page when he was supposed to land on the real page.
His address was, for example, 54.10.43.82, whereas I have RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^54.10.[0-255].[0-255], but he was still blocked.
When I checked the error.log, I realized that it was the client's IPV6 that was returned, not its IPV4, and this has happened to several people (not everyone, for others it picks up the IPV4 just fine).
Is there any way of forcing my server to return the ipv4 and not the ipv6?
Thanks
